# How Do I Add My Own Daemons in Arch Linux? (BSD-style init)

Tags: arch-linux, bsd, daemon, init

I have created a symlink to a start/stop/etc. wrapper bash script in `/etc/rc.d`, added it to `DAEMONS=()` in rc.conf, but the process it points to isn’t starting on boot, and isn’t showing up in the output of `$ rc.d list`. Googling around, I have seen mention of `update-rc.d`, but it seems that command is not available in Arch Linux. What is the right way of adding a system-wide daemon (i.e., without using `rc.local`) that can be used the same way as the defaults?

Comment: Did you mark the scripts executable?

Comment: [The ArchWiki explains Arch Linux' boot process in detail](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Boot_Process#init_and_The_Arch_boot_scripts), `rc.multi` takes care of `DAEMONS`.

Answer (score 5):

What does update-rc.d to do with Arch ? that's for debian based distros.

A sample script, put it in /etc/rc.d/XX and make it executable, and edit /etc/rc.conf, push the name of the service into DAEMONS array

```
#!/bin/sh

. /etc/rc.conf
. /etc/rc.d/functions

case "$1" in
        stop)
                stat_busy "Stopping XX"
                command_to_exec && rm_daemon XX && stat_done || stat_fail
                ;;
        start)
                stat_busy "Starting XXX"
                command_to_exec && add_daemon XX && stat_done || stat_fail
                ;;

esac

exit 0
```

If you're not seeing the daemon in list, you've probably missed the `add_daemon` function